# sed is appending code in the wrong place in all but one file in a directory

Tags: sed

I have the following tab indented code in a bunch of files in a directory:

```
  'oracleServers': dcoDatabaseServers,
  'oracleHomes': dcoDatabaseHomes,
  'sysPasswords': dcoSYSPasswords,
```

I want to add `'useOracleDriver': useOracleDriver,` after the 'oracleHomes' line in all files. I have this command:

```
sed -i "/oracleHomes/ a \\\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'useOracleDriver': useOracleDriver," $(find . -type f -name 'tc*')
```

When I run the command, the first file in alpha order with a tc* name, the text gets appended properly:

```
  'oracleServers': dcoDatabaseServers,
  'oracleHomes': dcoDatabaseHomes,
  'useOracleDriver': useOracleDriver,
  'sysPasswords': dcoSYSPasswords,
```

but with all other files beginning with tc*, I see the `'useOracleDriver': useOracleDriver` line, but it's appended to the very end of the file. Any idea on how to get the command to append in the proper place in all the other files?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce.  I ould check line endings, it looks like it is matching, but the append after the line is at the end of te file so maybe it thinks it is one line.

Comment: Did you experiment with `-s`option?

Comment: Can you simplify to a [mcve] with e.g. 3 files of 5 lines each, with simpler content? E.g. no tabs, no  `'`s.

Comment: You are not using one of those seds which do not understand the extension free `-i`, do you? I.e. check that ´-i` spec does not require something as a `.bak` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the sed command on each file individually, instead of all on a single `sed` execution:

```
find . -type f -name 'tc*' -exec sed -i "/oracleHomes/ a \\\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'useOracleDriver': useOracleDriver," {} \;
```

or

```
for f in $(find . -type f -name 'tc*'); do sed -i "/oracleHomes/ a \\\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'useOracleDriver': useOracleDriver," $f; done
```

The advantage of the second format is that, in the event you're not using GNU `sed` (and therefore have no `-i`), you can change it to

```
for f in $(find . -type f -name 'tc*'); do sed "/oracleHomes/ a \\\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'useOracleDriver': useOracleDriver," $f > $f.tmp; mv $f.tmp $f; done
```